# Jira Cloud: Need an API to get all users of a specific role (Administrators) for all projects and then post the result in a Confluence page

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Being all on Jira/Confluence Cloud, I need an all encompassing API script to run on Powershell and then on Github to do this complex job.
The ultimate goal: once a week update a Confluence page with a list of all of the users in every project's "Administrators" project role.

I have a script to post the license count into a Confluence page that works, so I know the last piece is possible. Where I'm struggling with is how to get all users listed for every project's project role Administrator.
My guess is to chain these two but that's why I'm here, to ask for assistance if there's anyone here that can help.

Pull list of each project
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-projects/#api-rest-api-2-project-search-get

Pull project role “administrator” per project
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-project-roles/#api-rest-api-2-project-projectidorkey-role-id-get

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.